# Icon font in Private Use Area (PUA) on iOS overwritten by emojis

Tags: ios, fonts, icons

- I got a task to prepare an icon font with 413 icons for 3 platforms (Web, iOS, Android).
- Names of icons are numbers from 1 to 413.
- I created a .ttf:

  - Icons are saved in Private Use Area (PUA).
  - Using e001 to e413 space while skipped hexes with letters i.e. `...e008, e009, e010, e011...`, as you can see I skipped `e00A-e00F`. I did that for easier manual input of data to avoid extra errors with mismatching numbers.
- This worked out well for Web and Android.
- Our iOS developer failed to use this font, because some of the icons return emojis instead of our icons.
- He told me to move the characters to a different block of space because iOS uses that space for emojis and he cannot do anything about it.

My question: **Is Apple really using *Private Use Area (PUA)* characters for emojis and my colleague cannot do anything about it?**